# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property | after creating a copy

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I wan't to copy an array (that is stored in my Redux Toolkit store), re-assign some properties and return it back.

I noticed that it works like this:

```
const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options));
copy[0].last = true;
```

But I wan't to do it like this but it throws an error:

```
const copy = [...options];
copy[0].last = true;
```

This error is thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'last' of
> object '#'

Why is `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` needed here to make it work?

The options are defined like this:

```
interface Options {
  label: string;
  first: boolean;
  last: boolean;
}

const options: Options[];
```

Comment: How exactly is `options` declared? That's what's dictating how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell exactly what's going on, because the nature of your `options` array is unknown. However, the difference between your first and second code sample is that the JSON routines *read* the `options` element values and then construct a completely new array, without all the details of writability from the original `options` values. In the second case, you've made a *shallow copy* of `options`, so the element objects are the same objects as in the original array. If a property isn't writable in the original, it won't be writable in your shallow copy.

*edit* — in response to your edit, some code somewhere is creating an object in the array such that the `last` property is not writable. I don't know exactly how or why, but it's easily possible to do that, either via `Object.freeze()` (which makes all the properties unwritable) or with `Object.defineProperty()` and the appropriate flag value for one of the properties.

Thus:

- something populates your array
- for whatever reason, some or all properties of some or all of the objects in the array are marked as non-writable
- you make a shallow copy of the array, which brings over references to the exact same objects that are found in the original array
- the properties are still not writable

In the original JSON version, the writability flags are not preserved in the to/from JSON transformation. (Note that transforming objects as JSON is not guaranteed to work in all cases, including many typical and common cases, because JSON serialization can only handle a small subset of JavaScript object possibilities.)

Comment: Now it makes sense. I use this package (https://react-select.com/) and the options here are the selected tags. So it can be that these are declared as read-only - right?

Comment: @Codehan25 yes, that must be the case, though how and why that package does that, I can't say.

Comment: So the only way is to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse here... Interesting...

Comment: @Codehan25 or make copies of the objects with your own code. Personally I dislike using the JSON routines, but that's just my opinion.